# Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: java

```
private static String[] food = {"bacon", "wings", "ham", "beef","morebaken"};
public MultipleSelLis(){
    leftlistik = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(food));
    leftlist = new JList(leftlistik.toArray());
    leftlist.setVisibleRowCount(3);
    add(new JScrollPane(leftlist));
    rightlistik = new ArrayList<String>();
    movebutton = new JButton("Move -->");
    movebutton.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                        rightlistik.add(leftlist.getSelectedValues());
                        leftlistik.remove(leftlist.getSelectedValues());

                        righrlist.setListData(rightlistik.toArray());

                }
            }
    );
    add(movebutton);
    add(returnbutton);
    righrlist = new JList();
  add(new JScrollPane(righrlist));
}
```

}

When I pick buttom get in "righrlist" something like "[Ljava.lang.Object;@..."

any help will be pleasure :)

Comment: Something like ... what do you mean by that? that is what is added? that is being printed? what?

Comment: Where are you getting the error? I don't see any casts to string in your code...

Comment: @JonSkeet: I doubt it's an actual casting issue, rather that he expects the value of the object printed, and he forgot to override toString or something similar.

Comment: getSelectedValues is causing the issue, try changing it to getSelectedValuesList

Comment: @IgorMalachov : getSelectedValues returns a list of Values, not one single value. so, you try to parse a list of Strings to a single String.

Comment: @Stultuske: Well the title suggests a cast. Basically the question isn't clear enough.

Comment: @anish Thank you, its works, but now I have in output "[bacon]",how I can get rid of "[]"

Comment: @JonSkeet : indeed, and it turned to be a cast issue after all, but the description taken into account, it could've gone all ways :)

Comment: @IgorMalachov: do you want one element? then use getSelectedValue, otherwise, use getSelectedValues, but read it in a list, iterate over said List and add the elements seperately.